# Can't render list of items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';

import Loader from './Loader';

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
        cards: {}
    };

    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'API_URL';
    axios.defaults.headers.common['KEY'] = "VALUE";
    axios.get('/cards')
      .then((resp) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          cards: resp.data
        });
      });
  };

  renderCards() {
    _.forOwn(this.state.cards, function(value, key) {
      return value.map((card) => {
        return <li>card.name</li>
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Loader />
        </div>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        {this.props.children}
          <ul className="cards-list">
            {this.renderCards()}
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Nothing is rendered through `this.renderCards()`.
I also tried `return <li>{card.name}</li>`, and even a simple string but nothing happens (no error, nothing in the DOM).

but if I change `return <li>card.name</li>`for `return console.log(card.name)`, the method log all the names in the console.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `return` the result of `_.forOwn`. Also your list item has to be wrapped with `{}` to get the value instead of a plain string.

```
renderCards() {
    return _.forOwn(this.state.cards, function(value, key) {
      return value.map((card) => {
        return <li>{card.name}</li>
      });
    });
  };
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Turns out _.forOwn returns the only the initial object. So the right solution would look like following:

```
renderCards() {
    let list = [];
    _.forOwn(this.state.cards, function(value, key) {
      value.map((card) => {
        list.push(<li key={card.cardId}>{card.name}</li>);        
      });
    });
    return list;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm one step further. However, I now have this error : "Objects are not valid as a React child" despite console.log(typeof card.name) returns "string"

Comment: hm, don't know how your data structure looks like and where your console.log is placed. Here's a stripped down fiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/gq52u3nk/

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud also you forgot key prop

Comment: Thank you, I think it's coming from my data structure, I'm trying to find what's going on thanks to your fiddle. My console.log is placed into the value.map (instead of the `return <li>`. And my data looks like this : http://pastebin.com/5bi1HeEt

Comment: Ok I achieved to make this work, but I'm not sure to understand why ... I've modified the renderCards method like this : http://pastebin.com/1EpaiU6z but I don't think it's really clever. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud Ah, yes. I see. `_.forOwn` just returns the initial object. Your solution is ok but you don't have to `push` your values manually to the array. `Array.prototype.map` already returns it. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrutsche/gq52u3nk/1/